# External live data into Adobe Business Catalyst

Tags: business-catalyst

Client got a Drupal 6 site with a lot of functionality.
They want to create a Adobe Business Catalyst site and "just take some parts" from the old Drupal site and implement in the new Adobe Business Catalyst site.

Need to fetch live data from the database and show in a block on new Business Catalyst site.
Are there any ways to do that instead of using iframes?

Comment: What data are you trying to access from the database?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Business Catalyst won't fetch any external data from another server or site, best start from scratch but import your content to BC data base.